# Symfony PHPunit Testing - how do I mock services?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm just wondering how you'd mock a service in Symfony.

This is what I've ended up with so far and it's not working as expected. I expect the `getVenuesData()` method from the `NetballFeedService` to dump the mocked data in the test (I've set a DD in the command). But when I run the test, it dumps the real time data being pulled from the `NetballFeedService`.

#### Test:

```php
    public function it_imports_venues(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $netballAPIMock = $this->createMock(NetballFeedService::class);
        $netballAPIMock->method('getVenuesData')->willReturn([
            800 => ['name' => 'Venue 1', 'location' => 'MEL'],
            801 => ['name' => 'Venue 2', 'location' => 'ADE']
        ]);

        $this->getContainer()->set('netballAPI', $netballAPIMock);

        $container = $kernel->getContainer();
        $container->set('netballAPI', $netballAPIMock);

        $application = new Application($kernel);

        $command = $application->find('app:feed:import-venues');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute([]);
        $commandTester->assertCommandIsSuccessful();
    }
```

#### Command being tested:

```php
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:feed:import-venues';

    public function __construct(
        private readonly NetballFeedService $netballFeedService,
        private readonly VenueService $venueService
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $data = $this->netballFeedService->getVenuesData();
        dd($data);
        $this->venueService->updateVenuesDataFromFeed($data);

        return 0;
    }
```

#### Class method expected to return mocked data:

```php
    public function getVenuesData(): array
    {
        $response = $this->client->request('GET', self::FIXTURES_URL);
        $rawData = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        $rounds = $rawData['data']['results'];

        $parsedVenuesData = [];
        foreach ($rounds as $round) {
            foreach ($round['matches'] as $matches) {
                $venueId = $matches['venueId'];

                if (array_key_exists($venueId, $matches)) {
                    continue;
                }

                $parsedVenuesData[$matches['venueId']] = [
                    'name' => $matches['venueName'],
                    'location' => $matches['venueLocation']
                ];
            }
        }

        ksort($parsedVenuesData);

        return $parsedVenuesData;
    }
```

#### I'm trying to replicate my Laravel test code in Symfony:

```php
/** @test */
    public function it_imports_venues()
    {
        $this->withExceptionHandling();

        $this->instance(
            NetballAPI::class,
            Mockery::mock(NetballAPI::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
                $mock->shouldReceive('getVenuesData')->once()
                    ->andReturn([
                        800 => [
                            'name' => 'Venue 1',
                            'location' => 'MEL'
                        ],
                        801 => [
                            'name' => 'Venue 2',
                            'location' => 'ADE'
                        ],
                    ]);
            })
        );

        $this->artisan('import:venues');

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('venues', [
            'id' => 800,
            'name' => 'Venue 1',
            'location' => 'MEL'
        ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('venues', [
            'id' => 801,
            'name' => 'Venue 2',
            'location' => 'ADE'
        ]);
```

#### `services_test.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    public: true

  App\Service\NetballFeedService:
    public: true
    alias: netballAPI
```

Just wondering how I can mock the `NetballFeedService` class in the test instance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was configuring the `service_test.yaml` wrong. It should be:

```yaml
services:
  App\Service\NetballFeedService:
    public: true

  app.netballFeedService:
    alias: App\Service\NetballFeedService
    public: true
```

Also, I'm not really used to using YAML files for configs. It's not very readable especially compared to it's PHP file counterpart in this instance. So I'll be experimenting on using both YAML & PHP files for configs/routes etc.